# RequestMethod POST and GET in the same Controller?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, request

First of all, here is my `Controller`:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/esta", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {

    Esta estaobject = new Esta();
    // To test, if the parameters are set
    String user = request.getParameter("user");
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String shortname = request.getParameter("shortname");
    String was_admin_string = request.getParameter("was_admin");
    String sap_nr = request.getParameter("sap_nr");
    String etl_string = request.getParameter("etl");

    if (user != null && name != null && shortname != null && was_admin_string != null && sap_nr != null && etl_string != null) {
        some code...
    }

    request.getSession().setAttribute("esta", estaobject);

    return "esta";
}
```

When I visit the site, it check with the `if`-statement, if there are some parameters.
If not, then it should just display my form. Then, when I fill the form, it send it with `POST` and now there are some parameters and it goes through the `if`-statement.

My problem is: When I visit the site for the first time, it isn't a `POST`-request, so I get the error message `Request method 'GET' not supported`.
But change the form to a `GET`-request isn't a option for me. It must be `POST`.

So is there a solution to handle the same controller in `POST` and `GET` Requests?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Make it an array of method values that it gets mapped to, like so:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/esta", method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
```

Comment: Oooooooooh boy. thats embarrassing... I forgot to "Clean Install" my class. Now it works. I'm sorry ^^ 
`+1` for the correct answer :P

Answer (score 2):

Or you can write separate methods

```
@RequestMapping(value = {#some_vale}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public random_method #1{
}

@RequestMapping(value = { #some_value }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public random_method #2{
}
```

now you can implement your to visit the specific page and another to fill the form.
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

In spring developer can use both RequestMethod.POST and RequestMethod.GET at same controller just making an array of method like that:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/esta", method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
public String handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
//Implementation of your code.
}
```